# how to minify the linux userspace on debian / ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, apt, package-managers

some times, i have to minify a debian or ubuntu-system. I need to reduce the packages to a very small subset:

- No x11 or other graphical stuff
- No Apache, MySQL
- No preinstalled (and old) rubygems

Things that should not get removed:

- boot until login-prompt
- dhcp and other tiny stuff to get networking up
- sshd

I would need a list of packages to keep, and remove all other packages installed on a system. Does anybody have such a list or another way to "vanillaify" a debian / ubuntu os?

Comment: I guess https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD should do the trick

Comment: my goal is not to reinstall the system. I want to leave it as is, but to purge most things down.

Answer (score 0):

Use `init=/bin/bash` as kernel parameter.